# How to hide only the regressions

Tags: highcharts

I have a 6 column chart with its 6 respective regressions.

Show all together is a little messy, and I want to hide all the regressions bu default.

I tried to use a chart.events and some other stuff, but it doen't works for me.

[Image of Final state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V2WM.png)

This is my series configuration:

```
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: '@Html.Raw(grafic.serie1.Title)',
            regression: true,
            regressionSettings: {
                label: '@Html.Raw(grafic.serie1.linearTitle)',
                type: 'linear',
                legendIndex: 1,
                stack: 0,
            },
            data: camp1Dades,
            legendIndex: 0,
            stack: 0
        },{
            type: 'column',
            name: '@Html.Raw(grafic.serie2.Title)',
            regression: true,
            regressionSettings: {
                label: '@Html.Raw(grafic.serie2.linearTitle)',
                type: 'linear',
                legendIndex: 2,
                stack: 0,
            },
            data: camp2Dades,
            legendIndex: 0,
            stack: 0
        },...]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you like to hide regression in the legend, am I right? If so, have you tried to set `showInLegend: false` in the `regressionSettings `?

Comment: I need to see "In Legend", but when loads I need regression item to be disabled, not hide. So that the user can use it later.

Comment: could you reproduce your issue on some online editor with the sample data?

Comment: Don't worry I use finally js to make a fake click on the element just after load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally use

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function (event) {
            $(".highcharts-legend-item").each(function (n, item) {
                if ($(this).find("tspan").html().includes(<filter-text>)) {
                    $(this).click()
                }
            });
        },
    }
},
```

Is no clean, but it works.